# Batch for loop, maybe I'm missing something

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, psexec

I know I can do this with Powershell but, well, more as a project to practice my Command Prompt Scripting skills, wanna do it with a batch file.  I have a txt file with ComputerNames, I want my loop to echo the name, then run SystemInfo and grab a particular line from the result.

Computers.txt reads like this:

```
 XPCOMPUTER1
 XPCOMPUTER2
 W7COMPUTER1
 W7COMPUTER2
```

My batch file looks like this:

```
For /F %%w IN (computer.txt) Do (echo %%w & psexec \\%%w cmd.exe & 
systeminfo | Find "Total Physical Memory:")
```

Which, should, list the host name, then PSexec into it and run SystemInfo and grab the Total Physical Memory, right? I thought so!  But I get

```
%%W was unexpected at this time.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass `systeminfo` as a parameter to `cmd` that you launch from `psexec` like this:

```
For /F %%w IN (computer.txt) Do (echo %%w & psexec \\%%w cmd.exe /c systeminfo | Find "Total Physical Memory:")
```

Otherwise your just executing `cmd` then `systeminfo`, `systeminfo` isn't running from `cmd`.

Also, unless it's a typo, you wrote `computer.txt` in the script and you said it was called `computers.txt`.

I'm not sure if that will solve the problem but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the best approach for me to solve this was to call systeminfo directly using psexec.

```
For /F %%w IN (computer.txt) Do (echo %%w & psexec \\%%w systeminfo | Find "Total Physical Memory:")
```

Which gives me back:

```
Total Physical Memory:     8,126 MB
```

Since I've now learned PowerShell, I would attack this problem totally differently though.

```
ForEach ($computer in (Get-Content Computer.txt) { 
  Get-CIMInstance -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | `    
Select Name,@{N='RAM(MB)';E={[int]($_.TotalPhysicalMemory /1mb)}}
```

Which results in:

```
Name       RAM(MB)
----       -------
AL-1NG43Q1    8126
LOCALHOST     8126
127.0.0.1     8126
```